# How do I add a Github library to my Android Project as a JAR in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to add https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip to my project. Looking at it, I notice that it has files in `res` and depends on its own `R.java` file. When I make it a JAR I continue to get errors because the dependencies aren't all there. I'm not sure how to get this to work.

I keep getting errors like

`import android.support cannot be resolved` and everything else too. I tried referencing different answers on StackOverflow but none of them yielded a working solution.

Comment: After looking more closely at that library, I strongly suggest that you switch to Android Studio. You will find it much easier to use the library.

Comment: Okay, I'll try Android Studio. Would I then have to import all my other libraries by Gradle as well? I use Gson, Google-Play-Services and Android-support-v4

Comment: Ideally, yes, you should use Gradle for all of your dependency management. This is great because you don't have to worry about what's in your `libs` directory and it's simple to update to a new version of each library when they are released.

Answer (score 0):

The resources won't be packaged into the JAR file. Google is working on a new packaging scheme called AAR which is supported by Android Studio.

In order to use this third-party library in your own project, you should clone it to a local repo. Then you can import it directly into your Eclipse workspace and then add the Eclipse project to the classpath of your app's project.

Comment: When I import it directly into the Eclipse workspace, I get an error, it has the error `the import android.support cannot be resolved` which makes sense because it isn't there, but it wouldn't have that issue if it was a library in my project because I include the `android.support` that it needs. How would I add it to the classpath of my project?

Comment: Gradle projects from Android Studio don't work in Eclipse as is.

Comment: @David You need to also add the support library to the classpath of the PagerSlidingTabStrip library.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm not sure how I would do that or how I would it to the classpath of my project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the whole source code from `https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip` by git tool.
2. On your `Eclipse IDE`, import the `library` as `exsisting source code` at `Android` option.
3. Add the library your add before into your project.